# Hiding textfield of webView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using google maps in my application but using a webView...I have loaded a webview see image[image]

I do not want that textfield ....

Is there any way to remove it

Please help

Answer (score 0):

worst comes to worst create a composite class that places a uiview over the text view, the text field is coming from google and not the webview so it would be something in the google api if there is something to turn it off, not sure how youre accessing it.

Comment: well how are you getting the map? u are using the api without knowing about it, possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use javascript to remove that element from the `UIWebView`. You can call javascript with this method: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

Though, given that it looks like your app uses maps, why not try using `MKMapView`? It's pretty easy to use and there are a ton of useful tutorials out there...

Comment: yeah if you can get away with using mapkit do it.